# Transparent QGraphicsWebview over QGLWidget leads to super imposed images

Tags: qt, opengl, opengl-es, qgraphicsview, qwebview

I have a transparent `QGraphicsWebview` inside a `QGraphicsView` with the following settings:

- The `QGraphicsView` is the high level widget, and is shown in full screen mode
- The graphics view uses a `QGLWidget` as its view port (to use opengl-es)

  - Alpha channel and double buffering are enabled in this QGLWidget
- Transparency is achieved by `graphicsView->setStyleSheet("background:transparent")`
- Following attributes are set for QGraphicsView and QGraphicsWebview

  - WA_TranslucentBackground = true
  - WA_NoSystemBackground = true
  - WA_OpaquePaintEvent = false
- The `QPalette::Base` and `QPalette::Window` brushes of webview and `webview->page()` are set to `Qt::transparent`

At the beginning, the transparency works fine. But as the screen get updated (when I scroll), it looks like the new bitmap is blended on top of the existing one to get a superimposed picture. After about 5-6 screen updates, this blending causes the colors to accumulate and form an opaque rectangle (with a corrupted image). Following images show first, second and final stages of the problem.

How do I tell qt/opengl to stop blending and just draw the new image to the frame buffer? 
I tried calling `fillRect(boundRect(), Qt::transparent)` from overridden Webview::paint and GraphicsView::paintEvent; but it didn't work except for making the updates slower.

I am new to Qt and OpenGl, so I might be missing some basic flags or settings.

[image: Three stages of background transparency]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is `graphicsView->setStyleSheet("background:transparent");`. Who would have guessed?!

Yeah, the line that I thought made transparency work was actually causing troubles with transparency. The application works fine without that line (or if you change it to `background:none`)

In short, steps to get a transparent QGraphicsWebview using QGLWidget:

- Set the Base palettes of `QGraphicsWebview`, `QWebpage` and the outer `QGraphicsView` to `Qt::transparent`
- `scene->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::transparent));`

You should also make sure that html body background is set to transparent values:

```
html, body {
  background-color: rgba(127, 127, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the methods mentioned above. They did not work for me. I then debugged into qtbase code and found that setting the Opacity level make the top browser layer transparent.

this->setOpacity(0.1);

this pointer points to the QGraphicsWebView object.

With this method, the whole front browser contents including background will be transparent. To separate header, paragraph and background and to specify different transparent levels for them, I will have to dig into webkit code a little further to figure out the problem. But for now, setOpacity() did the trick and is good enough for what I am doing.